# Overwrite file only if data

Tags: bash

I am trying to overwrite a file with command output, but only if there is any output. That is, I usually want

```
mycommand > myfile
```

but if this would overwrite `myfile` with empty data, I wish to retain the old version of `myfile`. I thought that something using `ifne` should be possible, a la

```
mycommand | ifne (cat > myfile)
```

but that does not work ...

An indirect approach

```
mycommand | tee mytempfile | ifne mv mytempfile myfile
```

works, but I consider the use of that temp file unelegant.

**Q:** Why does my first idea not work? Can it be made work? Or is there another nice and perhaps completely different solution for my original problem?

Comment: "Redirecting to a separate file, checking the size of that file and possibly renaming it" seems pretty straight-forward to me. Why not use a temporary file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first approach works, you just need to give a command to `ifne` (see `man ifne`):

```
NAME
       ifne - Run command if the standard input is not empty

SYNOPSIS
       ifne [-n] command

DESCRIPTION
       ifne  runs  the  following command if and only if the standard input is
       not empty.
```

So you need to give it a command to run. You're almost there, `tee` will work:

```
command | ifne tee myfile > /dev/null
```

If your command doesn't produce an enormous amount of data, if it's small enough to fit in a variable, you can also do:

```
var=$(mycommand)
[[ -n $var ]] && printf '%s\n' "$var" > myfile
```

Answer (score 9):

The pedestrian solution:

```sh
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

mycommand >"$tmpfile"
if [ -s "$tmpfile" ]; then
    cat "$tmpfile" >myfile
fi

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

That is, save the output to a temporary file, then test whether it's empty or not.  If it's not empty, copy its contents over your file.  In the end, delete the temporary file.

I'm using `cat "$tmpfile" >myfile` rather than `cp "$tmpfile" myfile` (or `mv`) to get the same effect as you would have gotten from `mycommand >myfile`, i.e. to truncate the existing file and preserve ownership and permissions.

If `$TMPDIR` (used by `mktemp`) is on a memory-mounted filesystem, then this would not write to disk other than possibly when writing to `myfile`. It would additionally be more portable than using `ifne`.